# How can I uncheck a checked box when another is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I know it's not a great practice to treat checkboxes as radio buttons, but I need the user to be able to deselect an option if they want to. I've got some jQuery that limits a user to one option but I need a checked option to uncheck when another option is selected. Right now the user has to uncheck the checked option and then select something else.

Here is the current script:

```
$(function () {
    var max = 1;
    $('#checks-wrap-app-type').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        return $(this).closest('#checks-wrap-app-type').find(':checked').length <= max;
    });
]);
```

I'm not sure how to alter this so that the currently checked option is unchecked when another option is selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try no uncheck all options in jQuery and then check needed one? There is no need to look for checked input.

Comment: Apparently @wared is not a reader.

Comment: @Feanor - Could you clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the change event instead, and on change, just uncheck all, not including the one just changed.

```
$('#checks-wrap-app-type').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    $('#checks-wrap-app-type input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: I had to rewrite some things to get it to totally work but this helped me get there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using radiobuttons instead? They'll do what you're needing done.

Comment: They won't because I need the user to be able to deselect the option, which can't be done with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
 if($('.checkbox1').prop('checked') == 'true')
      $('.checkbox1').prop('checked',false);

    if($('.checkbox2').prop('checked') == 'true')
      $('.checkbox2').prop('checked',false);
```